# When the short /i/ sound in English is lenthened very much (in singing, for example), will its quality change so it resembles long /i:/?

Tags: english, phonology, acoustic-analysis

In singing, when a singer lengthens a word that contains short /i/, will it cause any confusion (between that short /i/ and the long /i:/) for the native English speaker's ear?

When I listened to this [song](https://youtu.be/6QQQKJJBJOY?si=0QiYDBrY-GODWLYG) near 2':20s, I mistook "live" for "leave". Even when I tried to listen several dozen times more, I still got confused over which word the singer sang.

More generally, will it be possible for the acoustic feature of short /i:/ assimilate to long /i:/ in such case?

I haven't found any result mentioning this phenomenon, despite I know that some books do affirm that quality of short /i/ remains the same for the case of pre-lenis lengthening (but did't mention the case of singing).

Comment: I find some cases the lengthened short /i/ still possesses its distint quality from long /i:/, so no confusion arises (even the singer lenthened it sharply). But for this specific case, I got so confused, and some other cases also. I doubt there's some inconsistency here.

Comment: The singer is just lenthening the vowel sound. Not changing its sound at all. You can do that with any /i/. Biiiit Fiiiit. And then the t at the very end is less strong in these cases, for example. Try saying Ten feet and ten bits.  The sounds are completely different. You can also lengthen the ee in feet or leave, this one: /i:/). They are not articulated in the same positions. The singer is doing something with the l, not the /i/. I don't know what that's called. Will try to find it.

Comment: @Lambie on one occasion, I test this [recording](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mid) of the word "mid" (the UK accent) on a native speaker and he got confused too.

Comment: Ok, so I think the l is palatilized. Normally, in the word live, the front or tip of the tongue does not stay near the palate to make the l sound. It goes there and then drops. But that singer is prolonging the sound of the l by sort of "rubbing" the tongue against the palate.

Comment: Yes, that recording of the word mid is kind of weird. But even there, the person is **not saying** mead, as in leave.   If a person says say mid-ocean disaster, I don't hear a difference in the mid part between BrE and AmE. Same with the word middle. Are you in Vietnam or in an English-speaking place? I have an idea for you.

Comment: Yes, I'm in Vietnam but I use English most of the time for work.

Comment: I think you can find an English speaker and get them to say these to you in person. Then, it's easier to hear. English speakers simply do not confuse these two sounds.

Comment: @Lambie thats indeed a good aproach! Just one difficulty arises is that it's quite expensive to carry out such type of experiment so that **it's statistically meaningful**. What I mean is that having just a few participants (that I know, which is not a representative sample) won't give a persuasive conclusion. So I think it might be better to ask if some one has done it before.

Comment: Tran, listen to me please. This is not about statistics. My contention is that native English speakers (BrE or AmE) do not confuse those sounds. Therefore, you only need one to do what I am suggesting to you. For me, the issue seems to be that you are not "hearing it" and not that the singer is changing the basic phoneme of live to leave.

Comment: Fyi, I deal a lot with /i/ because French, Spanish and Portuguese speakers sometimes have a really hard time with, for example,  bit versus beet/beat when they speak English.  Because /i/ does not exist in those languages.

Comment: worth noting that some variaties of English (e.g. Standard Southern British English) do actually have a pure length distinction in certain vowels without a quality difference. In SSBE, KIT, NEAR (when not broken into two syllables under prosodic stress), and FLEECE have the vowels /ɪ/, /ɪ:/, /ɪj/ respectively, meaning that e.g. _bid_ and _beard_ are distinguished solely by quantity (with the KIT & NEAR vowels respectively). This distinction would be lost in singing, but the distinction between them and _beed_ (with the FLEECE vowel) would still be distinct

Comment: @Tristan We were discussing live versus leave in the song. The sound the guy makes is *not* leave for live. He is lengthening the the l and i sound, and palatizing the l.

Comment: @Lambie that is why my comment is a comment and not an answer. It doesn't directly address the question, but is relevant information

Comment: (obviously there is no counterpart to live/leave with the NEAR vowel)

Comment: @Tristan Well, if you bothered to read through my explanation, you'll see I'm having a hard time convincing the OP.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Songs are not the best source of acoustic data for understanding speech acoustics, because there is usually a lot of other distracting noise (multiple singers, instruments, etc), and singers deliberately distort the acoustics of ordinary language (khöömei, sygyt, kargyraa, falsetto...).

The high front vowels of English come in at least four surface types in terms of duration, that is English has [i:, i, ɪ:, ɪ]. Vowels get shortened before voiceless codas, hence the phonetic difference in vowel duration in "bead" and "beat", or "bid" and "bit". (Perhaps there are dialects where there is instead lengthening before voiced segments but in GAE as far as I have observed it is pre-fortis shortening and everything else is "default duration").
The tense vowels are generally longer than the lax vowels, and as you see from these words, this gives you an at-least 4-way duration continuum. The phonological analysis of the distinction is somewhat controversial, but the tense/lax distinction best matches "long/short" on typological grounds (limits on tense vowels mirroring limits on long vowels in other languages). However, "tense" and "lax" is itself a typologically anomalous distinction. There are various African languages with a distinction transcribed as [i, ɪ, e, ɛ] where the vowels are full-fledged distinct phonemes, not alternative analyses of a length distinction (as it is in Hindi, English and Arabic), and in those African languages, we use the term "Advanced Tongue Root".

You can always find some speech token that engenders perceptual confusion. However, if you approach the question in a controlled experimental fashion, duration of vowels has a low degree of influence on word identification, compared to formant values. If F1 of /ɪ/ is abnormally low, abnormally high duration might result is mis-identification.

Comment: thanks for your thorough answer! For the last statement, i.e "If F1 of /ɪ/ is abnormally low, abnormally high duration might result is mis-identification.", it sounds very logical and reasonable to me. But I'm just curious to know if there's any book, statistics or published paper mentioning this?

Comment: You can lengthen or shorten any sounds like live or leave when singing. The singer in that song merely lengthened the sound and palatalized the l in a way that accommodates singing. What is a speech token?? And he is not trying to understand speech acoustics. He is trying to account for his claim that the singer is changing /i/ to /i:/

Comment: A "token" is a specific instance, it's a concept that applies to anything (it's distinct from "type" which covers all of the "tokens"). Speech is "speech", i.e. linguistic vocalization, as contrasted with some other use, such as music, hallucination, or rote repetition as actors often do when required to read lines in a language that they have no knowledge of.

Comment: @TranKhanh, it's actually remarkably difficult to find perceptual studies on the contrast using native speakers of English as the subjects: zillions of studies on L2 acquisition of English. I will look for a systematic study.

Comment: pre-fortis clipping is purely allophonic, and a much smaller difference in duration than between genuine long and short vowels, so representing it using : is extremely misleading imo. I.e. beed, beat, bid, bit have vowel durations _in that order_, so giving a long diacritic to bid and beed, but not to beat is untenable

Comment: An answer to this question does not require studies. It's too simple. My issue is that I am not sure I explained the phonology of what that guy says when he makes the word "live" longer than usual but with no change in vowel sound.

Comment: This answer to me is very sound and valid under both acoustic/phonetic points of view. I don't know who downvoted it but what I'm asking here is not restricted to phonetic features of the sound but also about auditory/acoustic linguistics for which the answer provides necessary information about what is being asked.